# Evaluation of integrals with floor functions

Tags: definite-integrals, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Given the following integral
$$
\int_{0}^{1102}\lfloor \sqrt x \rfloor dx
$$

What are the ways available to compute this integral? I've tried plugging it into the integral calculator on desmos.com and it gives an answer of 23825

However, when I tried manually expanding this equation, i,e

$$
\int_{0}^{1102}\lfloor \sqrt x \rfloor dx =\\= \int_{1^2}^{2^2} 1 \space\ dx + \int_{2^2}^{3^2} 2  \space\ dx + \int_{3^2}^{4^2} 3 \space\ dx \space +...+ \int_{32^2}^{33^2} 32 \space\ dx + \int_{33^2}^{1102} 33 \space\ dx
$$

I get a value of $23837$. Is there something extra I'm accounting for in my expansion and calculation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Integrating Floor Functions $\int_0^{1102} \lfloor{x^{1/2}}\rfloor \mathrm{d}x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3878900/integrating-floor-functions-int-01102-lfloorx1-2-rfloor-mathrmdx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you are correct:

$$
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{1102}\lfloor \sqrt x \rfloor dx &= \sum_{k=1}^{32}\int_{k^2}^{(k+1)^2}kdx + \int_{33^2}^{1102}33dx \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{32}k(2k+1) + 33(1102-33^2)\\
&=2\sum_{k=1}^{32}k^2  + \sum_{k=1}^{32}k + 429 \\
&=2\frac{32(32+1)(64+1)}{6}+\frac{32\cdot 33}{2} + 429 \\
&= 22880 + 528 + 429 \\
&= 23837
\end{align}
$$

One can see that the area (integral) consists of many rectangles where $k^\text{th}$ rectangle ($0$-indexed) has, indeed, area of $$k\big((k+1)^2-k^2)\big)=k(2k+1)$$

---

Below is the graph of the function:
[image]

Comment: I see thanks for the help!